# Understanding modprobe.conf

Tags: linux, modprobe

#### Questions:

- Can someone help me understand the following

**Note:** trivial information from `/etc/modprobe.conf`

```
 install foo /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install foo; /sbin/start_udev
 alias char-major-10-32 foo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I begin from button. Alias is a simple alias, instead you call `modprobe char-major-10-32` you can use `modprobe foo` with the same effect, or vice versa.

Install is like a kind of alias too. 
With

`install foo /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install foo; /sbin/start_udev`

You be able to call

`modprobe foo`.

If you do so the system then executes

`/sbin/modprobe --ignore-install foo`

followed by

`/sbin/start_udev`.

`--ignore-install` in this case is not necessary.

**From the manpage:**
*For example, if the module  "fred"  works better  with  the  module  "barney"  already  installed (but it doesn't depend on it, so modprobe won't automatically load it), you could say "install fred /sbin/modprobe barney; /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install fred", which would do what you wanted. Note the --ignore-install, which stops the second modprobe from running the same install command again.*

Comment: @zzeroo: thanks, but which is the "...second modprobe" and why is "--ignore-install" not necessary please?

Comment: Hmmm difficult ;) by the way that's really rare stuff modern kernel autoload modules very fine. Now back to the problem.
E.g. "exotic-file-system" and "exotic-hd" are two modules you want to load. You want if you `modprobe exotic-file-system` that "exotic-hd" is installed to.

`install exotic-file-system /sbin/modprobe exotic-hd; /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install exotic-file-system`

--ignore-install stops the second modprobe from running the same install command again.

Answer (score -1):

man modprobe.conf

If that doesn't tell you what you need to know, can you ask a more specific question?

Comment: @pbr: Thanks - I'm aware of the man page, but I do not understand the description. My question is specific :-)